# Custom post type author issues

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I've created a CPT called 'artigos' (articles), which supports title, editor, thumbnail and author. I can see and choose the author of the post, but in the users screen, the number of posts assigned to an author doesn't change, and the author page can't find the articles.

Am I missing something?

```php
function custom_post_type_artigos() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Artigos', 'Post Type General Name', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Artigo', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Artigos', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Artigos', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Arquivos dos artigos', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Atributos do item', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Item pai:', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'Todos os artigos', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Adicionar novo artigo', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Adicionar novo', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'Novo artigo', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Editar artigo', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Atualizar artigo', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'Ver artigo', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'Ver artigos', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Procurar artigos', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'NÃ£o encontrado', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'NÃ£o encontrado na lixeira', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Imagem destacada', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Definir imagem destacada', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remover imagem destacada', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Usar como imagem destacada', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Inserir no artigo', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Enviado para este artigo', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Lista de artigos', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Navegação em lista de artigos', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filtrar lista de artigos', 'viverbrasil' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Artigo', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Artigos dos articulistas da Viver Brasil', 'viverbrasil' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        //'capability' => 'organize_shop',
        //'map_meta_cap'    => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'artigos', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_artigos', 0 );
```

Comment: Found the issue: Woo Memberships. Trying to solve it now...

Comment: Problem solved: I created a author page and a loop: 'post_type'=> array('post', 'artigos'),